# Using Apache to relay wss (web-socket) protocol to backend

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass, websocket

I'm using Apache 2.4.27.  I need to tunnel a client's `wss` request through an Apache reverse-proxy, to a backend server.  However, from a tcpdump, it appears the `wss` request is being rejected by the Apache server.  So I'm trying to debug this first hop.

The client issues a `wss` request:

```
wss://apache-server/wss/app
```

The Apache error_log displays:

```
AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /wss/app. If you are 
using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are
included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Meanwhile, in my httpd_access_log:

```
HTTP/1.1 "GET /wss/app HTTP/1.1" 500 528
```

It seems, Apache is interpreting it as a `HTTP/1.1 GET` request and not `wss`.  Could this be true?

I need Apache to accept the `wss` connection and relay/tunnel it to a backend server.

Is Apache 2.4.27 able to accept `wss` connections?  Do I need some other protocol module that is not bundled with Apache 2.4.27?  [I saw [Apache-WebSocket](https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket), but it is 6 years old, so I'm guessing it is defunct.]

Any suggestions to further debug this will also be greatly appreciated.

PS: I have loaded: `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_wstunnel`, `mod_proxy_http`, `mod_proxy_html`, `mod_proxy_connect`, `mod_proxy_ajp`, and a bunch of others.

Comment: The initial websocket connection comes as an HTTP GET request with an Upgrade header, which apparently Apache isn't interpreting. See Protocol Handshake in [Websocket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Comment: Please show your ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse statements.

Comment: After much head scratching and your initial comment about "Apache isn't interpreting", I put a check <IfModule proxy_wstunnel_module> and found the wstunnel was not loading!  I corrected that, and the tunnel started working.  Now I'm onto my next issue... sessions clobbering each other.  Thanks for your input Andrew, it helped!